# Is vbscript executable in edge browser ie mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, microsoft-edge

I have an old webpage with VBScript.
We are testing edge browser compatibility in ie mode.

> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Internet Control Panel > Security Page > Internet Zone

I allowed VBScript to run in Internet Explorer settings, but
VBScript doesn't seem to work.

Does edge ie mode support VBScript?

Comment: Which Edge? If it's the latest Edge it's based on the [Chromium Project](https://www.chromium.org/Home/) so the answer would be no, in fact, I'm pretty sure VBScript browser support ended around IE 9-10 pre Edge.

Comment: @LesFerch it entirely depends on what they mean by "edge browser ie mode".

Comment: Tangentially related, I recently had to update an old classic ASP webpage that runs on vbscript server-side (Server 2012) and it works fine for chrome and edge-chromium.  Worst case scenario if you really can't update the web application is put the vbscript on the server side in IIS and run it with classic ASP.

Comment: @Lucretius running VBScript server-side is completely different to running it client-side and for completely different reasons. Often client-side code needs to interact with the Internet Browser which unlike server-side code which doesn’t care what Internet Browser is used because it’s the servers job to process it and return a result to the client. You’re mixing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute VBScript in Edge IE mode if you set IE mode Compatibility mode to IE10.

You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies) to configure IE mode using group policies. The steps are like below:

1. [Enable Internet Explorer integration using Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#enable-internet-explorer-integration-using-group-policy)
2. [Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy)

For how to create the Enterprise Mode Site List, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/add-multiple-sites-to-enterprise-mode-site-list-using-the-version-2-schema-and-enterprise-mode-tool). To load the site in IE10 Compatibility mode in Edge IE mode, the sample sites list file is like below:

```
<site-list version="4">
  <created-by>
    <tool>EMIESiteListManager</tool>
    <version>12.0.0.0</version>
    <date-created>04/12/2022 06:53:26</date-created>
  </created-by>
  <site url="localhost:44364/vbs.html">
    <compat-mode>IE10</compat-mode>
    <open-in>IE11</open-in>
  </site>
</site-list>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Good to know. It's worth pointing out that it isn't running in Edge (as such) it's running in IE 11 using IE 10 Document Compatibility mode.

Comment: @user692942 I just tested this with Windows 11 (which includes MSHTML but does not have IE) and it worked just fine. It appears that when Edge is in IE mode, it uses MSHTML. This totally makes sense. It would be totally impractical to emulate IE using the Chromium engine, but pretty easy for Microsoft to make Edge capable of using two different engines. In IE mode, Edge is essentially IE without the COM interface.

Comment: After doing some more testing, I see that Microsoft is pulling some neat tricks. Internet Explorer is only "removed" from Windows 11 from a user perspective. When Edge is in "IE mode" it's still Internet Explorer behind the scenes and not just Edge using MSHTML. When you switch Edge to "Internet Explorer mode", iexplore.exe is launched. Killing iexplore.exe with `taskkill /f im iexplore.exe` causes the page, displayed in Edge, to "have a problem". The Internet Explorer COM interface also continues to work in Windows 11. It's just  matter of setting the compatibility mode.

Comment: MS hasn't said that IE is / will be removed from Win11 :)  They've said that the "IE11 Desktop Application" is removed from Win11.  IE is still "part of the operating system".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Edge supports VBScript in IE mode (even in Windows 11) because, as stated by @user692942, it's really iexplore.exe that renders the page using MSHTML, as long as the compatibility mode is set correctly.

If you don't set up a compatibility mode site list, as per the answer from @Yu Zhou, you can also just set the compatibility mode in your old web page. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
</head>
<script language="VBScript">
Sub Greet
  MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
</script>
<input type=button value='Click for greeting' onclick=Greet()>
</html>
```

In addition to configuration via GPO, the above page will display in Edge (via iexplore.exe) on any PC with the following steps:

1. In Edge Settings go to **Default browser**
2. For **Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode** select
   **Allow**
3. Reload Edge if prompted to do so
4. From the **...** menu select **Reload in Internet Explorer mode**
5. When prompted, click **Allow blocked content**

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No.

Basically, both Legacy Edge (EdgeHTML engine) and its successor Edge (which harnesses the [Chromium Project](https://www.chromium.org/Home/), also known as "Edgium") are not based on the MSHTML engine used by the Internet Explorer browser (IE 11 and below) which supported ActiveX technologies which included Active Scripting languages like VBScript and JScript (IE 10 and below).

As pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71823337/is-vbscript-executable-in-edge-browser-ie-mode#comment126929668_71823337), it is possible to run IE 11 in IE 10 mode and open pages containing VBScript.

Comment: Not sure what the down-vote is for, end of the day Edge-ium can’t run VBScript but it can run the IE 11 engine which can run VBScript in specific document modes.